# Connecting LDAP Server on Windows ADFS Server (default password?)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adfs2.0, adfs, google-directory-api

I have windows server running ADFS server. I want to Connect to ldap server on it. My questions are

1. Does running ADFS Server already have LDAP Server running or need to do anything for that? I believe it is running already because I could see open port 389 and 636.
2. Assuming LDAP server is running, I was trying to connect to it using Google App Directory Sync to get list of users However I was not able to authorize. Is there any default credentials to connect? Or steps to get credentials for LDAP server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An ADFS server is not an Active Directory server - ADFS only extends Active Directory's infrastructure. Ports 389 and 636 are available because ADFS supports the LDAP and LDAPS protocols for communication, and as such, ADFS can retrieve user attributes from Active Directory, and it can also authenticate users against Active Directory. If you already have a directory server running, you need to add it to ADFS as an [account store](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787806%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
2. There are no default credentials - just use an administrative account that exists in your Active Directory store, as mentioned in point one.

Comment: Thanks. Btw I already have setup ADFS server as SAML Identity provider and added few users in ADFS. SAML single signon is working. Does it mean account store is already setup?

Comment: @hridayesh Yes, by default you'll have a local account store behind your ADFS instance. I just wanted to illustrate the difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks! I saw there is open ldap port also. Just dont know credentials of Active directory running behind ADFS.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify on terminology for ADFS:

- Account Store in ADFS: This is the account store that ADFS authenticates the user against with some form of credential (e.g. Username/password). By default ADFS connects to the Active Directory Domain Services and adds it as a special account store that cannot be deleted. So, any users in this active directory forest or in it's trusted subsystem can authenticate to ADFS. So far, ADFS only supported Active Directory as an account store and nothing else. With Windows Server 2016, it now supports connecting any LDAP v3 compliant directory as an account store. ADFS does not open LDAP ports as it is not an LDAP server. If ADFS were collocated with a domain controller, you would see LDAP ports open.
- Attribute Store in ADFS: This a store where you can augment additional information about the user **AFTER** the user authenticates. By default ADFS has a default attribute store for ADDS that is setup by virtue of the install. Beyond this, it has in-built adapters that can be instantiated to connect to SQL or ADLDS (lightweight directory service). It also has an extensible API to connect to any other attribute store of your choice via .NET. People connect to Oracle/SAP data base, FIM metaverse etc.

@Srikanth: You will use the ADFS claims language or the UI to query for additional data using the attribute store model. In the UI, you would see it when you configure the issuance authorization rules or the issuance claims rules.

Hope that helps
Sam (@MrADFS)